# parse rows based on columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which stores row information in a concatenate format such as:

```
    LOCATION_COLUMN
[Country]*[city]*[town]
```

I want to extract the country )before the first aster ix part of it, [Country], while eliminating the *[city]*[town]. I could complete this using a scripting language such as php which has great parsing tools, but if I could I like to complete the task inside of mysql. Looking at documentation I can't find any parsing techniques (there seem to be some parsing plugins for mysql), but I would like to keep the database as it is as it is used for many other things. Native sql syntax such as the commands `LIKE` I do not believe as be used as you need to know the characters you are looking for, but in my case I am not looking for specific characters, just want to extract the country parts. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: String functions work, as in the answer provided. More generally, mysql supports regular expression matching as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the components are separated by asterisks, you can use:

```
select substring_index(location_column, '*', 1) as country
```